# Property 'pipe' doesn't exist on type any[] | Observal<Object>

Tags: angular

I am trying to build using 'ng build --prod'. but I am getting an error like

> Property pipe doesn't exist on type any[].

### Component code:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>

text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap(() => this.searching = true),
  switchMap(term => term.length < 2 ? []:
    this._service.search(term).pipe(
      tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
      catchError(() => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
       // return of([]);
        return [];
      }))
  ),
  tap(() => this.searching = false)
)
```

### view code:

```
<input id="typeahead-http" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" 
 #input
(selectItem)="selectedItem($event,input)"
[class.is-invalid]="searchFailed"
[(ngModel)]="model" 
[ngbTypeahead]="search"
[inputFormatter]="formatter"
[resultFormatter]="formatter"  />
<span *ngIf="searching">searching...</span>
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Sorry, this product could not be loaded.</div>
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I am using angular 6